# tomcat6 sqlnet encryption failure

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, encryption, oracle11g

Recently inherited an old Java codebase that makes use of tomcat6 with apache and am attempting to set up a dev environment.  I'm getting an ORA-12649 code ("Unknown Encryption or Data Integrity algorithm") when calling DriverManager.getConnection() via the front-end JSP logon screen.

There are a number of things that do not make sense:

1. we have implemented encryption (via settings in slqnet.ora) on the target db which runs Oracle 11gR2, and it works with the production version of the same codebase; it also works with incoming sqldeveloper connections, etc.; basically, there have been no problems with the encryption implementation on the db side
2. the development codebase is exactly the same as the production codebase (at this point in time)
3. the development tomcat6 installation is the same version as the production installation
4. if I point the connector at another db that does NOT implement encryption, the authorization succeeds with a valid username and password

After extensive reading through Oracle documentation and forums, tomcat6 documentation (specifically the convoluted way it handles the CLASSPATH variable) I have come up empty.

My hunch is that the tomcat6 install on the dev system is not referencing the correct jar files even though I have the ojdbc6.jar file in the tomcat install lib folder.  According to Oracle, having ojdbc6.jar available should just work when it comes to implementing this type of encryption from a thin client, which is how this tomcat app is implemented.

Here's how encryption is being implemented on the client side; this compiles without error:

```
...
prop.setProperty(
    OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_LEVEL,
    AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED);
prop.setProperty(
    OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_ENCRYPTION_TYPES,
    "( " + AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES256 + "," +
           AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_3DES168 + "," +
           AnoServices.ENCRYPTION_AES192 + " )");

// require the use of the SHA1 algorithm for data integrity checking
prop.setProperty(
    OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_LEVEL,
    AnoServices.ANO_REQUIRED);
prop.setProperty(
    OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CHECKSUM_TYPES,
    "( " + AnoServices.CHECKSUM_SHA1 + " )");
...
```

Here are the pertinent lines in the sqlnet.ora file on the db side, which is known to work with multiple clients:

```
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=required
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=(AES256,AES192,3DES168)
sqlnet.crypto_checksum_server=required
sqlnet.crypto_checksum_types_server=(SHA1)
```

This is the db url being used in tomcat's web.xml file in the application directory:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@<my_db_name>:1521:<my_db_sid>
```

My context.xml file implements the 'allowLinking' feature, not sure if that makes a difference but it is non-standard so I'm including that detail.  This allows me to provide a symlink in tomcat's `<webapps>` folder that points to the proper location in my repo.  The directory permissions are OK since tomcat is serving up pages from that location.

```
<Context path="/<my_app_name>" allowLinking="true">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ojdbc6.jar file referenced in the CLASSPATH during servlet compilation was different than the ojdbc6.jar file referenced by tomcat6.  My working assumption was that contents of any file named "ojdbc6.jar" is static, but apparently I was wrong!  (Can anyone confirm if Oracle does indeed release different versions of the file named "ojdbc6.jar"?  I couldn't find any evidence that they do).

After much more time spent on this, I became convinced that the issue lay in the driver version being used even though the jar filename was "ojdbc6.jar" across all instances.  So, I used md5sum to confirm that both .jar files were the same, and sure enough, they were not!  So I re-downloaded ojdbc6.jar from Oracle and copied it to both locations where it was needed, recompiled my servlet classes, and restarted tomcat6.  No more errors on login over the encrypted connection.

So it appears that someone had the grand idea of renaming an older/invalid version of an ojdbcX.jar file to ojdbc6.jar in the past.  I don't even want to know why.  :)